# Do test HAVE to be written first in TDD?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, agile

This morning I had a conversation with a co-worker about TDD.  In his opinion to truly do TDD, the tests have to be written before the code.  I argued that as long as your tests are driving your code and your making decisions (e.g.: injecting dependencies, Single responsibility etc...) based on the feedback from the tests that you're doing TDD.  So I argued that there should be a distinction between Test First and Test Driven.

I understand the TDD rules, I've read the books, blogs and agile forums.   So far everyone that's chimed in around here has given me the book text definition of TDD.

The reason why I'm reaching out to this group is because we know "the solution is not in the text book".  Plus I need to know that I'm not the only crazy person who thinks this is reasonable :)

Do test have to be written first in order to do TDD?  What is your opinion?

Comment: I think this is a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: How can a test drive development if it doesn't yet exist?

Comment: @steenhulthin - So...what am I supposed to do?  copy and paste this on stackexchange?, a site that I have never used and knew nothing about 'til now.  I guess stackoverflow was supposed to be the destination for all dev questions, topics discussions.  Has that changed?  What's next? a Stackoverflow paysite?  I just want to know so I can start saving now :)

Comment: You can do this if it works for you. For me, I like a concrete test  so that I can visualize it and then "drive production code design". I'm not that good at juggling things in my head. In any case, since you are spending so much time thinking about it.. why not write the test while you're at it.. what's the benefit of just writing it later ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the important thing is that it's an iterative process where the iterations are very small. So if your first step is to create a file and make a bare-bones class with one method stubbed out, then write a test that calls that method and fails, then I think that it doesn't matter much which file you created first. You have to decide what the thing you're creating is going to look like enough to write a test that calls it, who cares what order you save the files in? But if the iterations get much larger than that then you're probably not doing TDD. Writing the whole class upfront as one big iteration would definitely not count as TDD.

Comment: Definitely agree with you that the sequence of events is irrelevant. +1 on writing the entire class upfront wouldn't count as TDD.

Comment: @Buzzer: yes, the idea is to benefit from tests as you're writing the code, it should lead you toward testable designs and provide more feedback, by frequently going back and forth between the code and the tests. in contrast if you do like some of my co-workers and put off writing tests until after the functionality is written, the test-writing becomes pointless drudgery.

Answer (score 0):

in pure TDD, the tests are written first.  If the team has the necessary discipline, I personally think its OK as long as tests drive the development.  Nothing is 'done' until there are tests covering all the functionality.

Comment: So are you saying that one cannot do TDD and Refactoring together?

Comment: @buzzer where did i say that?

Comment: Sorry you're right you didn't explicitly said that. I was just referring to the comment about "in pure TDD, the tests are written first" which implies that in a refactoring effort one cannot do pure TDD.  I'm in 100 agreement with the rest of your statement.

Comment: @buzzer TDD and Refactoring go perfectly well together.  If you have some code, and you have some tests, as soon as you start refactoring your tests will (should) break.  So in that case you can either 1) change the code then change the tests or 2) change the tests and then change the code....